# Compare two rdd and the values which match from the right rdd put it in the rdd

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have 2 rdd

```
rdd1       rdd2
1,abc      3,asd
2,edc      4,qwe 
3,wer      5,axc
4,ert
5,tyu
6,sdf
7,ghj
```

Compare the two rdd and once which match the with the id will be updated with the value from the rdd2 to the rdd1.
I understand that rdd are immutable so I consider that the new rdd will be made.
The output rdd will look something like this

```
output rdd       
    1,abc      
    2,edc       
    3,asd      
    4,qwe
    5,axc
    6,sdf
    7,ghj
```

Its a basic thing but, I am new to spark and scala and trying things.

Answer (score 1):

Use `leftOuterJoin` to match two RDDs by key, then use `map` to choose the "new value" (from `rdd2`) if it exists, or keep the "old" one otherwise:

```
// sample data:
val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(Seq((1, "aaa"), (2, "bbb"), (3, "ccc")))
val rdd2 = sc.parallelize(Seq((3, "333"), (4, "444"), (5, "555")))

val result = rdd1.leftOuterJoin(rdd2).map { 
  case (key, (oldV, maybeNewV)) => (key, maybeNewV.getOrElse(oldV)) 
}
```

Comment: I am using scala spark is it possible ? I am not getting leftOuterJoin in eclipse recommender

Comment: `leftOuterJoin` is indeed not a member of `RDD`, but it is available via implicit conversion (into a `PairRDDFunctions` instance) assuming `rdd1` is of the form `RDD[(K, V)] for any types `K` and `V` - in other words, that both RDDs are RDDs of _tuples_.

Comment: added sample data for your convenience, if it helps.